# OnValidateIdentity SecurityStampValidator without regenerateIdentity

Tags: asp.net, identity

**I experience that the POST request I send to the backend is not executed because of this line in the SecurityStampValidator on OnValidateIdentity:** https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/main/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin/SecurityStampValidator.cs#L98
`var identity = await regenerateIdentityCallback.Invoke(manager, user).WithCurrentCulture();`

What are the consequences of not adding a regenerateIdentity function?

With regenerateIdentity: `OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>( validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),         regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))`

Without regenerateIdentity:
`OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>( validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2), regenerateIdentity: null)`